# R - Regex - Replacing multiple \r\n (CRLF) with one \r\n

Tags: regex, r, text-processing

I have tried gsub( "[\r\n]+", "\r\n", textDoc ) but it seems to treat \r and \n individually, rather than as a single string?

EDIT -

```
"This is a line! It ends with a CRLF!\r\n

\r\n

\r\n

There is more stuff down here! I want it directly below the other stuff! Get rid of those two blank lines! Actually, ANYTIME I have blank lines, lets remove them!\r\n"
```

Comment: More clarity on this question is needed.

Comment: Added in an example string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[\r\n]+` uses a char class with `[]`. That's how char classes work.

You want `()` for a capture group:`(\r\n)+`

Edit:

There were some issues with implementing this, as it was inserting an extra `\r`.

After many comments, I guessed that the replacement should be just `\n`, and it added a `\r\n` (as intended).

I'm not entirely sure WHY this is happening, but I think that somewhere along the line, to ensure cross-system compatibility, `\n` maps to `\r\n`, thus `\r\n` maps to `\r\r\n`.

Comment: I originally thought that too, but I wind up with an even worse situation than I started with.  Not only do I have the multiple CRLFs, I now have an additional CR at the end of each line.

Comment: When I try that, I get an even worse solution. See the result here : http://imgur.com/a/KoIeO  The top is after, the first is before.  Note the first line ends with CRLF, its just out of frame.

Comment: @Jibril Undo? It may not behave like a normal regex... let me look into it.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to undo it.  Yeah I've noticed some weird differences and am not sure how to properly research it.  Things like this work on Regex tester sites, but then in practice its not.

Comment: [Here](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/sub) gives me the idea you should try `perl=TRUE`.....(and also rawr, who posted while I was typing)

Comment: Same result, sadly.  I am baffled as to what is causing this.

Comment: Maybe try `[\n\r]+[\n\r]+`?

Comment: Same result.  The most confusing part is where the random lone CR's are even coming from.

Comment: WAIT A SECOND... Try removing the one CR from your replacement

Comment: I just did that myself to test! Works beautiful! Can you explain why using \n in the replacement gives both CRLF?

Comment: @Jibril: is it possible that the `\r` and `\n` in your R source code *already get translated* to literal characters before being handed to its regex parser? If so, double the backslashes so the regex parser receives a literal string "\r" (which it ahould parse per common regex rules) instead of the code for a CR (and likewise for the LF).